# 503 error while uploading django project in server

Tags: django, deployment, server, cpanel

I've program written in django and tried to upload in server
i've uploaded the project in cpanel and tried to setup in python app
in first image there is command to run in terminal
i've also tried doing that

now i'm getting 503 service unavailable

This is my first time hosting so i dont know that is going wrong!!
https://prnt.sc/Dy4PiphauS1c

https://prnt.sc/aRVB9NDgdWzx

https://prnt.sc/osZW-oDow123

Comment: add some extra data to your question like the content of the WSGI file: passinger_wsgi.py and the logs file of the app in the C-Panel app directory

Comment: you should accept all connection, by `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` Only for testing purpose.. | You should use webserver like gunicorn and ngnix in deployment..